# Javascript redirect impact on SEO

Tags: javascript, redirect

Not sure if this is the best place for this question but it's something I've been really curious about. I'd like to use data only available on the client side for loading resources/assets for a website, such as device-pixel-ratio, touch support, etc.

The content on the page will not be changing, just resources like JS files, CSS files, and image files.

There are a few scripts already out there that work like this that run client-side tests and then store the data in a cookie, and then reload the page, loading resources based on data stored in the cookie.

The process works as follows:

- User comes to the site
- JS sets cookie with device features
- **JS reloads current page**
- Server can now access the cookie with all the feature data
- Can conditionally load resources and assets based on this data

Is this a bad practice to immediately reload the page as the user comes to it. Are there any SEO drawbacks to this method. It seems like a great technique for conditionally loading resources based on device capabilities. I'm just not sure if there are any reasons not to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many web crawlers do not use full Javascript or cookie functionality. For instance, GoogleBot does interpret *all* Javascript by default. Thus, all the content you are dynamically loading as a part of your cookie may not be detected by the crawler and will not be indexed as a result. This kills the SEO.

As a quote from Matt Cutts (Google's webspam guy):

> "For a while, we were scanning within JavaScript, and we were looking
>   for links. Google has gotten smarter about JavaScript and can execute
>   some JavaScript. I wouldn't say that we execute all JavaScript, so
>   there are some conditions in which we don't execute JavaScript.
>   Certainly there are some common, well-known JavaScript things like
>   Google Analytics, which you wouldn't even want to execute because you
>   wouldn't want to try to generate phantom visits from Googlebot into
>   your Google Analytics".

**Reference**: http://www.searchnewz.com/topstory/news/sn-2-20100315SEOInterviewwithMattCutts.html

Comment: The content on the site would not be changing, only the resources. I'm thinking of a mobile first site where the basics resources are loaded initially, and after the page refresh, additionally resources are loaded, like additional CSS for displays bigger than mobile, JS files for touch optimization, if touch is supported. The idea is rather then sending everything over the line, testing with JS, then reload the page, and sending over just the resources the device is capable of. Again, the content would not be changing, just the resources/assets.

Comment: If this is the case, it should be fine for SEO.

Comment: That's what I was kinda thinking. I read through this: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66355
and this technique doesn't sound like cloaking, sneaky Javascript redirects, and doorway pages. It's really just a client-side/server-side progressive enhancement technique that would not alter content.

Comment: The problem is that it might *look* like cloaking, sneaky redirects or doorway pages to Googlebot. Then you are busted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, search engines usually neither support cookies nor JavaScript, so they will get the default version only.

And some search engines may test for that and might see this as a "doorway page" (and thus punish the site). I wonder if one of the reasons they started their own web browser was as a side product of developing a robot that checks for such things. Obviously, the robots needs to be fast in JavaScript...

Comment: I'm curious about this "doorway page" concept. My thinking is that search engine bots would get the same content as the enhanced version. The only difference is the search engine/users without JS would never get the enhanced CSS or JS.

Comment: They might not even bother to check the contents for identity. The browser is being redirected immediately, meaning that the first page is not visible to the user. Google does not want you to do this.

Comment: Hmm... this is interesting. What makes you think that the searchbot would not check the content for its identity? I was under the impression searchbots would not run a JS redirect and would just load the base page without the optimized CSS/JS for the device.

Comment: Usually they would not load everything. But Google *might* by now be checking for pages that do nasty stuff with JS, such as redirecting. Because they need to detect doorway pages; and it is a known fact that they punish this. So if the Googlebot assumes this is what you are trying to do, it will give you negative points.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Sounds like I will have to do some testing to see if this technique gets frowned upon from Google. Thanks for the feedback @Anony-Mousse

Comment: You may not notice immediately. I'd try to find a way to have it work without redirects. Why don't you just load the appropriate contents via Javascript? There is nothing wrong with image and css replacement I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly would not like the page to reload when I've just started using it.

You should probably be using media queries (for the CSS) and feature detection (for JS).

```
@media all and (min-width:420px) {
    /*styles...*/
}
```

And:

```
if( typeof window.localStorage !== "undefined") {
    // you can now do stuff with localStorage.
}
```

Comment: The page would run the feature tests, "Modernizr" at the start of page load, set the cookie, then refresh. This would all happen before the page even started to render so the user shouldn't see the refresh. It wouldnt be like they would see the site and be able to interact with it and then it all of sudden refreshes.